# Issue stubbing current_user with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I am making a rails 4 app using devise to handle my user auth, which has not given me any trouble in any other controller or its tests. However when I go to stub in current_user in my comments tests (it is a polymorphic association) I keep getting:

```
Failure/Error: allow(comment).to receive(:current_user).with(:user)
#<Comment id: nil, author_id: nil, content: "This is a Comment", commentable_type: "Question", commentable_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> does not implement: current_user
```

I have googled around for this and have not found anything helpful, I have used the devise suggested ControllerHelper method to control testing logins and it has not helped. I can't figure out the source of this error, so even that much would be extremely helpful.

This is the rspec that is giving me trouble:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
allow(comment).to receive(:current_user).with(:user)
```

Here is the Comment Model code:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :author, presence: true

  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Can you show a Comment model code?

Comment: Is it a controller test? Or a model test? Or a feature test? Can you show us this spec? For me it's absolutely unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_user` is a controller or helper method in Devise (look at [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L56) code) but you a trying to mock it in model. It doesn't have `current_user` method, for this reason the `rspec` raise exception.